# "Native Crash At" happened to my App' users

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, crash-reports

I have a working App in Google Play which is only beneficial if you live in my Country.

I saw a Crash(In my Play Console Account) happened twice in different times to my users called "Native Crash at"..

I tried to understand the Stack Trace of the error, yet I couldn't.

My app is written in Java by using Android Studio, so I'm not sure what does this error mean by "Native" or ".so" files in the Stack Trace..

My app has a service which has multithread code to do the background work:
(Thread 1 started -> call thread 2 if completion 1 or call thread 3 if completion 2.)

I have no problems with the threads, no IllegalThreadStateException..

Could someone explain to me what does this error mean in my situation ?

I'm not sure what block/function/class of code I should provide to help explain this because I'm unable to find the related(where the error occurred) Java file or whatever is necessary.

[An image of a Stack Trace of an error called "Native Crash At"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbCnU.jpg)